# Python: parse an XML in Windows-1251 encoding

Tags: python, xml, parsing, encoding

When I try to parse XML with lxml like this:

```
tree = etree.parse('xml.xml')
```

I get the following error:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Unsupported encoding windows-1251
```

How can I read data from an XML with this encoding?

Thank you

Comment: Ah, the joys of Windows encoding

Comment: What platform are you on? This encoding works for me using lxml on Ubuntu Lucid.

Comment: Does the xml file have an xml declaration, and if so, what encoding does it specify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you use a Python 2.x version.

If so, I believe that you must use the open() function of codecs module, and to do:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(filename,'rb','cp1251') as f:
    content = f.read()
    tree = etree.parse(content)
```

I think that the obtained **content** has been decoded from *cp1251* to *Unicode*; I am not sure, I am not skilled in Unicode manipulations.

If so, I suppose that, after the reading,  etree must be able to parse a string in Unicode to continue. But I know **etree** a little too.

Note that even if mode was **'r'**, **codecs.open()** always opens a file in binary mode.

Hope that will help

Comment: @Alex Please, don't post the same question several times. You had already answers in another thread of answer to the same question when I saw this one

Comment: eyquem, yes I solved the problem with codecs.open(). Sorry for posting another similar question, but it's quite different.